# How to hide a window from the taskbar when started using System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, process, taskbar

I am writing a code that open a program like :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process aProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
aProcess.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(
    System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
        Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @"MyApp.exe"));
aProcess.Start();
```

MyApp.exe is not a dot net program. I want to hide the icon of this program from the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
aProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree Tom Studee.
If you want to display window and hide icon in the taskbar,please set ShowInTaskbar=false of the window in the MyApp.exe.